# JSX element literals with partially supplied properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using `React.cloneElement` one can provide additional properties to partially-filled (for lack of a better word) elements. A contrived example would be:

```
function createPopulatedElement(el, v) {
    return React.cloneElement(el, {value: v});
}

const ImportantContent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
       return (
          <strong> {this.props.value} </strong>
       );
    }
});

let populatedElement = createPopulatedElement(<ImportantContent/>, 'foo');

ReactDOM.render(populatedElement , $('#app2')[0]);
```

Now given that `<ImportantContent/>` in the code above evaluates (?) to:

`<strong>{this.props.value}</strong>`

... I would like to be able to just do:

```
let populatedElement= createPopulatedElement(
    (<span>{this.props.value} </span>),
    'foo');
```

... without having to declare a wrapper React class (`ImportantContent` in my case above). However the above code fails with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

... which sort of makes sense. Is there a way to supply a partially populated (for lack of a better word) element to some function or ReactJS component (that will then add additional properties) as a JSX element literal without having to create a class?

(The above code is a SSCCE and I know that the separate `createPopulatedElement` function doesn't make sense as I can directly pass `value={'foo'}` when I instantiate the `ImportantContent` component.)

## update

ctrlplusb suggest using a stateless functional component. This is indeed slightly better than a class:

```
let F = (props)=>(<span>{props.value} </span>);
let populatedElement= createPopulatedElement(
              <F/>
          , 'foo');
ReactDOM.render(populatedElement, $('#app3')[0]);
```

... but still, a new type (`F`) is introduced. Directly using an anonymous arrow function to make it even more compact and to avoid introducing a separate type fails parsing:

```
let populatedElement= createPopulatedElement(
         <(props)=>(
                <span>{props.value} </span>
                   )
         />
     , 'foo');
```

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to achieve, what's wrong with the first approach ?

Comment: @Pcriulan nothing's wrong. I would just like to avoid having to declare a class if I could instead use a simple "element literal".

Comment: Or use a stateless functional component if you are class averted?

Comment: @ctrlplusb updated the question; this is better but still a new type is introduced. It appears that an (anonymous) arrow function literal cannot directly be used.

Comment: What do you want to absolutely avoid new type creation ? Do you have an exact use case to provide ? Because it's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: @Pcriulan I don't like the idea of creating ad-hoc types where a literal of some kind ought to have been enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there - when you create a stateless component and use it in one go you'll need to wrap it by hand in [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) rather than using JSX:

```
let populatedElement= createPopulatedElement(
  React.createElement(props => <span>{props.value}</span>),
  'foo'
);
```

Comment: I think you need to pass `{value: 'foo'}`.

Comment: @Marcus: I wonder how. `props` have to be an object. There is a dev validation check that it is one. I don't see anything in the code that would turn the string into an object. Either way, even if it works, you should pass an object.

Comment: @FelixKling The function `createPopulatedElement` constructs the object in the call to `React.cloneElement` where it does:  `return React.cloneElement(el, {value: v});`

Comment: @Marcus: Doh, somehow I didn't realize the value is not directly passed to `ceateElement`. But why have that indirection? Why not use `React.createElement(props => ..., {value: ...})` directly? No need for another function.

Comment: @FelixKling this is a SSCCE for a situation where a helper function is needed to add additional `props` based on some logic that cannot be expressed in a one-liner.